# How can I programmatically perform an update through mongodb c# driver?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to perform an update on an object on the fields of the object that are not null. I know that I can simply require the object be fully populated before it reaches my update function, but I would rather the consumers of my function only pass in the values that have been changed (and keep all the others null). So the issue is how can I tell mongodb to do something similar to the Update.Set() for only the non null fields of my object? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. So, it's not `Update.Set`, but what is it?

Comment: In Update.Set you need to specify which field to update by giving it a string value. I don't necessarily know which fields I need to update, so I can't give Update.Set a string value for the necessary fields.

Comment: Presumably your application knows what field the user needs to update? Can you give us an example of a document as well as an example of an update that will take place?